# Cant Port forward in Dlink DIR 600M

Tags: windows, portforwarding

I have a dlink router..Dlink DIR 600M...I am trying to port forward 1337 and 1334 through my router and opened listener  but after enable i checked canyouseeme.org but theres no port opened..i have a cable net connection...my wan ip and public ip is different.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions. The [help] has more information if you need it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your WAN IP address and your Public IP addresses are different, you will need to be sure that you first port forward from the public-facing router to your D-Link router. If you do not have access to your public facing router (as is the case with my current network setup), then this port forwarding is not possible.

I have a DIR-651, and there are check boxes next to all the Port Forwarding rules. Make sure those are checked. I've wasted hours of troubleshooting because one of the boxes wasn't checked and saved.

Finally, make sure that you have a server running on the correct IP address and port that you specified on your router. Also, make sure that your firewall is disabled on those ports. If your server isn't configured to respond on those ports, then canyouseeme.org will not respond that those ports are open.